# Share only text if file attachement failed via ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I have an issue while sharing both text and file using Share Intent.
When i select Gmail to share, it takes both text and file but as we all know, we cannot share files via Whatsapp. So what i want is if file attachment failed then only text should be share but its not happening.
I am using below code:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.putExtra(
                android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "Test Messge");
        intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Please suggest some.

Comment: please learn about Receiving Simple Data from Other Apps you wll got your answer http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have mentioned, you cannot make Whatsapp do or behave the way you want. If Whatsapp doesn't handle the text and Uri together and chooses to ignore it, there is not much we can do about it.

However, depending on how badly you want this to work gracefully, you can:

**Approach 1:**

1. Get list of packages that match with your intent by using:

> ```
> PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
> List<ResolveInfo>     resolvedInfoList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
> ```

Here,

> ```
> resolvedInfoList[i].activityInfo.packageName
> ```

gives you the package name.

2. Show your own UI with a list of these apps. When the user chooses the app, you will know which app the user has selected.
3. Now if the choosen app belongs to a list of apps that you know can't handle file Uri's with text (in your case WhatsApp), create an intent with only the EXTRA_TEXT.
4. call startActivity with an explicit intent for the chosen package.

Depending on your need, you can leave out the EXTRA_TEXT or EXTRA_STREAM for apps that do not handle both.

A word of caution : This means that you will need to maintain your own UI. User experience will differ from the chooser you see if startActivity was called with an implicit intent. Most manufacturers as well as platforms customize the chooser activity. So if you need to conform to the native experience, this approach should not be taken up.

**Approach 2:**

Reverse engineer Whatsapp code into smali code using [ApkTool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/wiki/SmaliDebugging) to learn more how it is handling your intent when both EXTRA_TEXT and Intent.EXTRA_STREAM in it. You can just open the activity smali file and follow the onCreate() code. This will hopefully give some idea if you can do anything at your side or not.

Disclaimer : Reverse engineering app and code is a grey area legally. From what I understand, do not use the code directly for commercial gains. For personal understanding, it is mostly fine.

Comment: @Sonali8890 Great. It will be interesting to know how exactly did you solve it.

Comment: Nice answer! But I was having a doubt in first approach. If whatsapp is already shown in the listing of both EXTRA_TEXT and EXTRA_STREAM share apps, then using ur solution, shouldn't it be showing the whatsapp in the same list?

Comment: @berserk Thanks. I didn't understand your question entirely. Can you be more descriptive. I am guessing whatsapp declares an intent filter for multiple mime types. So when we resolve an intent with both EXTRA_TEXT and EXTRA_STREAM, whatsapp will likely be a solved app (even though as Sonali reports that it does not handle both together correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. You can't know which app the user will select.

I'd suggest giving the user the option to share as "email" or "text", and creating your intent based on that choice.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but my requirement is not that. I am working  on an share app which shares files with some extra text and i can't give an option to user what he wants to send because he believes that he is sending only files.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is that the data you send will be based on the app. Like whatsapp don;t receive files and receives text only. But as @DenleyBihari said, it is not possible.

Just think logically. The data an app receives is based on the Activity they created for receiving ACTION_SEND. You cannot choose what they must accept. And there can be any number of applications, so you cannot tell which application receives which content.

Comment: i am agree with you but as from developer site we can set some standard extras for the intent, if the receiving application is not designed to use them, it simply ignores them. So according to above line if i am putting an file to an intent then whatsapp will ignore that extra but it should except Intent.EXTRA_TEXT text.

Comment: @Sonali8890 Exactly! Absolutely correct! So what do you want?

Comment: I want if apps like whatsapp doesn't except files then it should ignore files and except text only.

Comment: @Sonali8890 That purely depends on the app on which u are sending intent. IF they have some support like that in their activity, it will do what u said. If they don't have support like that, it won't. I hope you are familiar with how an app receives intent.

Comment: I am familiar but my doubt is when i am add only this line intent.putExtra(
                android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "Test Messge"); then its sending text succesfully but when i add this extra line to send file   intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris); its ignoring the text. Why so?

Comment: @Sonali8890 Because they don't support it. I depends what they coded inside receiving activity.

Comment: They support because i have seen it working in other apps.I need to do some more research. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Sonali8890 Here by "they", I meant whatsapp. If it is working in other apps, it doesn't mean it will work in whatsapp too. It all depends on the app. Anyways, good luck :)